# Meaning of "bombastic" nowadays

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Wiktionary's defintions of "bombastic" are:

1. adj. of a person, their language or writing Pompous or overly wordy.
2. adj. High-sounding but with little meaning.
3. adj. archaic Inflated, overfilled.

"They are cheerful for a while, they are ***bombastic*** for a while and they then become slightly moronic," such a Brian Blessed said in an [interview](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2165250/RICHARD-KAY-Brian-Blessed-stormed-black-tie-event-heckler-criticised-film-role.html) published on Mail Online.

Which of the above definitions is the most accurate in describing "bombastic" in the way this word is used in the Blessed interview?

I am under the impression that, in that context, the right word is "violent" and it seems that Blessed's usage is influnced by the fact that "bombastic" starts with "bomb", a word that, as is well known, is "synonym" of "violence".

Comment: The full sequence BB describes is *cheerful > bombastic > moronic > insulting*, so it is very unlikely that the second stage is *violent*. Self-satisfied people who follow the arts are given to spouting high-flown critical phrases under the misapprehension that they understand **a)** what the phrases actually mean and **b)** how they are properly employed.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the second in this context. In the OED’s definition, ‘inflated or turgid language; high-sounding language on a trivial or commonplace subject’.